# how add my place on google map to my website?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web

I want to add a location to my website. my business location  It is added to google. I want show it on my web page like this.  I am using PHP. Google API did not highlight my location like this. How i add the map and highlight it.

[link to see my place.](https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Kanivu+Charitable+Trust/@9.650376,76.367668,5z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1skanivu!3m1!1s0x3b087e74cea1f4b7:0x93fa22a41aac4d75?hl=en)

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?zoom=20&center=9.6502435%2C76.3675044&key=************************">
</iframe> 
<div id="map-canvas"></div>*
```

I am using this to show map. It does not highlight my place, is there any way?

Comment: When you know your place  simply create a marker at the given location

Comment: share your code what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you just need to zoom in closer before you create the embedded map.  I see your place "highlighted" when I do that:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d7866.698261635076!2d76.36893404541627!3d9.651179823938902!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0000000000000000%3A0x93fa22a41aac4d75!2sKanivu+Charitable+Trust!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1433709664971" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

**code snippet:**

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d7866.698261635076!2d76.36893404541627!3d9.651179823938902!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0000000000000000%3A0x93fa22a41aac4d75!2sKanivu+Charitable+Trust!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1433709664971" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```